# Silverlight OOB (Out of Browser) Using Facebook Graph API

Tags: silverlight, facebook, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob, oauth-2.0

I'm building an out of browser Silverlight app and trying to use the Facebook Graph API, but I'm having trouble getting through the authentication round trip.

I've gone through their Desktop Application Authentication process:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/desktop

But I'm stuck on this step:

- Intercept the redirect above and read the access token out of the URI.

I've tried adding an event handler to the LoadCompleted event of my WebBrowser control, but NavigationEventArgs.Uri is always null:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.loadcompleted(v=VS.96).aspx

How am I supposed to get an access token from Facebook if I can't get the current URI out of WebBrowser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go here and get the silverlight sample app from the Facebook C# SDK on Codeplex.

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/

Get the source and you will see the samples.  There will be a full release in the next few days with separate downloads for each sample.

Comment: I see the code sample you're referring to, but it looks like you're relying on a development web server to host the "same domain" page that invokes the app through js. How does this translate to production where a user downloads and runs a .xap themselves?

Comment: The "Out of Browser" section of Microsoft's Silverlight Deployment Guide (.docx linked from here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/extreme/archive/2010/04/29/silverlight-4-deployment-guide.aspx ) clears up my confusion.  Either a .xap is installed from a website in which case that site's domain is used for same domain policies, or it can be installed using a command line tool, in which case there is an "origin" switch to set the domain to be considered "same domain".  In either case, hosting a callback page on that domain allows libraries such as this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded the latest code but i can't build it... it's stating:

Error   1   The type 'System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.    C:\facebooksdk2\facebooksdk_db7aa5e188e2\Source\Facebook\JsonSerializer.cs  161 31  Facebook-SL4

but i can only add a reference to system.xml of version 2.0.5